# Application crashes when trying to pass data on a NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I have the following code to pass a specific ID after 5 secs:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:currentID] forKey:@"ID"];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(checkID:) userInfo:dict repeats:NO];

- (void)checkID:(NSTimer*)t{
    NSInteger timerID = [[[t userInfo] objectForKey:@"ID"] integerValue];
    if (timerID == _myID){
       NSLog(@"got ID");
    }
}
```

But my application just crashes after the timer ends. Any ideas? I've searched around for help, but I can only find code like the one above and apparently it works for other people.
Thanks

Comment: ARC or MRC? If you are not using ARC then you should release dict.

Comment: What is the scope of `timer`? It is hard to tell here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, it worked fine for me. Not using the name as DigiMonk wrote in his answer is fine, but that's not what fixed your problem. Did you change something else as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it works here but without the "timer" property.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: currentID ] forKey:@"ID"];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(checkID:) userInfo:dict repeats:NO];
```

I think you don't need the "timer" property in this case.

Comment: Tough the answer has been accepted and it worked for the OP, I think that this can lead to a problem: if the autorelease pool gets drained the timer doesn't live anymore and the method doesn't get executed.

Comment: run loops retain their timers, don't think that will happen. The only thing here is that we don't have a reference to the timer that we can use but the timer exists and is valid until it's fired.